# Matlab: Plotting the conditions output of symbolic solve

Tags: matlab

I have a loop where I symbolically solve for intervals. Each iteration of the loop gives exactly one interval, for example:

```
v=[x+1,-x+4];

v = v > 0;

sol=solve(v,x,'ReturnConditions',true);
cond = sol.conditions;

ezplot(cond)
```

Would I be able to plot the 1x1 symbolic array " cond = -1 < x & x < 4 " at a y value of my choosing? When I use ezplot it always plots at y=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe by multiplying the `cond` by the `y` value you wish to use. In that case the title must be changed to match the original condition, `cond` by casting it as a string. In the example below I plotted the condition/region at a height of `y = 2`. To implement this in the for-loop I'd probably make a `y` a vector a retrieve one value/cell upon each iteration.

[image: Condition Plotted at a Specific Amplitude]

```
syms x
v = [x+1,-x+4];
v = v > 0;

sol = solve(v,x,'ReturnConditions',true);
cond = sol.conditions;

y = 2;
ezplot(y*cond);
ylim([0 y*1.2]);
title(string(cond));
```